# Ruby - mathematics operations

Tags: ruby, math

I tried a few minutes ago simple math operation

```
<%=((3+2+1)/100).round(8)%>
```

The result is **0.06**, but the result of the ruby code above is **0.0**. I would expect the result should be 0.060000.

Why not?
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
(3+2+1)/100
```

is `0` because the division is integer. Try

```
(3+2+1)/100.0
```

You see, if both arguments of `/` are integer, the result of the division is an integer (the whole part). If at least one of the arguments is floating-point, then the result is also floating-point.

Comment: Another option is fdiv.      6.fdiv(100) #=> 0.06

Comment: @steenslag: I don't even know Ruby... at all :) It's just that my answer is true in all the languages I do know :).

Comment: @Armen Tsirunyan: Ever heard of Perl, awk, Haskell? ;-)

Comment: @undur_gongor: Yes, I've heard about them, but I don't *know* them

Answer (score 4):

The dreadful integer arithmetic attacks again!

When you calculate ((3+2+1)/100), since all the operands are integers, Ruby uses integer arithmetic rather than floating point arithmetic.

If you do 7/100 it will also return 0, as it's rounded down to the nearest integer, which is 0.

Answer (score 2):

Operations involving only integer data are done in integer (and then `6/100` is `0`). Converting that `0` to float later (by `round`) does not bring you back the already discarded fractional part.

Change either of the values to float (e.g. `3.0`) and you are done.